# array_search returns 0 when any member is null

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, not all keys have a value (in this case, first member only):

```
$a = array("a", "b" => 4, "c" => 193);
$idx = array_search("c", array_keys($a)) ;
var_dump($idx);
```

This returns `0`;

In case I set `"a" => 123` then I get the correct return value (2).

Why can't `array_search` return the correct index of keys, even if not all of them have values?

Comment: you can not set $a's a key value blank.

Comment: You should probably do `"a"=>null` if you want "a" to have no value.

Comment: @NigelRen :  tkausl's answer is better than changing `"a"=>null`

Comment: @C2486 (apologies if incorrect) I think the misunderstanding is that OP is assuming that putting `"a"` means this element has no value, when in fact it creates it as (effectively) `0 => "a"`.  Not saying there is anything wrong with tkausl's answer, just trying to clarify why the problem may be happening.

Comment: @NigelRen : please don't apologize, we are here to discuss

Comment: I also think there's a bit of a smell around using `array_search` and `array_keys` together - the point of using `array_search` is to find the key that matches to a given element of data, but if you're removing the relationship between your keys and your actual data then this doesn't seem helpful. Specifically for this code, what use is the eventual `$idx` variable?

Comment: @NigelRen Guys, does someone know who are the guys who permanently vote-down the questions? is not the question legitimate? I dont know and that's why I asked question.

Comment: @C2486 same question too.

Comment: Sorry but I've never understood that either.  I'd rather post a comment and help people understand the problem, IMHO learning is about understanding what is wrong and not just down-voting something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because [`"c" == 0` is `true`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b32b5cba1d9a412f4d7469098dbec647833cf09b) and your first key is `0`.

pass `true` as third argument to `array_search`

> mixed array_search ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )

Comment: why c==0 is true?

Comment: @Wils : try `echo (int)"c";`